# Uuencode displaying attachment content in email body

Tags: scripting, email, perl, mailx

I am using uuencode with mailx to attach a zip file. In following code, the if block works perfectly and I get Deletions.zip as an attachment in the email. But, whenever the else block is executed I don't get the attachment but the binary code in the email body instead.

Code (Perl code invoking linux commands):

```
open(EF,'>', "/test/emailbody.txt") or die $!;
if ($#dzones != -1) {
        unshift @dzones, "Following files have 20% or more deletions --\n\n";
        unshift @dzones, "Start time: $localtime\n\n";
        my $localtime = scalar localtime();
        push @dzones, "End time: $localtime\n\n";
        print EF @dzones;
        `cd /test/DOUT/; zip -q9 /tmp/deletions.zip ./*.*`;
        `(cat /test/emailbody.txt;uuencode /tmp/deletions.zip Deletions.zip) | mailx -s "Device deletions" vishal\@test.com`;
} else {
        push @dzones, "No files have more than 20% deletions.\n\nPlease see attached for the deletions in different zones.\n\nThanks, Vishal\n\n";
        print EF @dzones;
        `cd /test/DOUT/; zip -q9 /tmp/deletions.zip ./*.*`;
        `(cat /test/emailbody.txt;uuencode /tmp/deletions.zip Deletions.zip) | mailx -s "Device deletions" vishal\@test.com`;
}
close(EF);
```

When else block is executed, all I get is:

````````
begin 644 Deletions.zip
M4$L#!!0``@`(`.U6,D4]>N/[=0$``&@&```D`!4`9&5L7VYE7T%L8F5R=&%?
… [snip] …
+`"H+``"R'```````
`
end
````````

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd close `EF` or flush it before running that `cat /test/emailbody.txt` command, in case the output is being buffered.

Comment: Yes, I thought that too but it's not resolving the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the causing problem is being caused during looping of while `cat /test/emailbody.txt;`

Remove the "," while printing in file. Following line of code has this problem:

`push @dzones, "No files have more than 20% deletions.\n\nPlease see attached for the deletions in different zones.\n\nThanks, Vishal\n\n";`